# Is it correct that the normal approximation is just approximation of the normal distribution?

Tags: normal-distribution

In mathematics statistics. I'm a bit confused by the terminology *normal approximation*. What is it? Is it just something you say when you approximate, for example the normal distribution?

Comment: I think this term usually means that you are approximating some other distribution using a normal distribution. One sometimes sees a distribution called "approximately normal" with the same meaning. For example, the mean of a large number of independent identically distributed RVs is approximately normal, and the approximation becomes better as the number of variables grows.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a discrete distribution like Binomial or poisson and if you are getting an approximation to these in normal distribution that is called Normal approximation

Answer (score 1):

By the central limit theorem, the distribution of the mean of many independent and identically distributed random variables is approximately normal. When samples from some distribution are taken, the individual samples are considered as coming from independent but identically distributed random variables, so it is often assumed in calculations that the distribution is normal so that the wide body of knowledge associated with the normal distribution can be applied. The assumption is approximately validated by the central limit theorem and could be referred to as a normal approximation.